# GAE/J datastore backup

Tags: java, google-app-engine

What is the easiest way to do a GAE/J datastore backup?

It looks like there is python bulkloader.py tool to do backup for Python apps, but what should I do to backup Java app? Is there any way to use python tool?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible to use python tool bulkloader.py to create datastore backup of GAE Java app. You just have to set up remote_api by adding following lines to web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app>
  <!-- Add this to your web.xml to enable remote API on Java. -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>remoteapi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoteapi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>remoteapi</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

After that you can use bulkloader.py with --dump to download backup and with --restore to upload backup to datastore.

Comment: The security-constraint part can now be safely removed (AppEngine 1.4.3), as the Servlet itself now also performs this check

Comment: This is not a valid solution with HR datastore: "If you attempt to download data, you'll see a high_replication_warning error in the Admin Console, and the downloaded data might not include recently saved entities."

Comment: Please see [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12458521/1328880) for steps required to use RemoteApiServlet

Answer (score 2):

Or if you can, you may wait for the datastore backup-restore feature in GAE upcoming versions as seen in the roadmap. 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old, but this came out as a feature of the [Datastore Administration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin) in the app-engine dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Just set up remote_api for your app using the directions [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) - notably the tip:

> Tip: If you have a Java app, you can
>   use the Python bulkloader.py tool by
>   installing the Java version of the
>   remote_api handler, which is included
>   with the Java runtime environment. The
>   handler servlet class is
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet.

Then, use the Python bulkloader with --dump or --restore.

Comment: can bulkloader --dump do incremental downloads?

Comment: No. There's currently no generic way to do incremental downloads, since App Engine doesn't expose a total order over entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the managed export and import feature, which can be accessed through gcloud or the Datastore Admin API:

[Exporting and Importing Entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities)

[Scheduling an Export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export)