# backup and restore options for GAE/J

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I know that utilities for backup and restore are in the GAE future
roadmap, but until then I need to do some backup/restore operations on
the data store of my GAE/J application.
  I found some info on how to enable the remote API for GAE/J
applications by setting up the RemoteServlet in the application's
web.xml and then you should be able to use the bulkloader.py tool from
the python sdk to do backup/restore operation on the datastore of a
GAE/J app ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364310/gae-j-datastore-backup)).
  I've added the remote API servlet in the web.xml, deployed it and
the remote API seems to be active since I get the "This request did
not contain a necessary header" message in the browser. However when
trying to use the bulkloader.py tool with the remote url and my
developer credentials, I get an message from the python tool:
URLError: (urlopen error (10060, 'Operation timed out')) with the
Authentication Failed info message.
Did any one encountered this problem and managed to solve it? Some
pointers would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: You need to show us the command line and complete stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but I found the problem meanwhile - it was the company proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was the company proxy, so I requested the URL of my app be removed from the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [GAEBAR](http://github.com/aral/gaebar)