# Export/import datastore from/to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to export the datastore that I have running in App Engine into my local "standalone" version of the application. Anyone know how I can do that?

I've been looking around in the App Engine dashboard but can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the docs on [uploading and downloading data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html).

Comment: Nick, what about java? I only see this option for python. on a side note, can you take a look at this question for me too please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778095/appengine-datastore-change-entities-property  ?

Comment: @WinMyoHtet It's not really specific to Python - you can upload and download data to any instance.

Comment: As of 2017 none of this stuff works anymore. Your best bet is to take a look at this question and the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530199/how-to-upload-data-in-bulk-to-the-appengine-datastore-older-methods-do-not-work.

Answer (score 5):

[Gobo-Tools](http://code.google.com/p/gobo-tools/) is designed for such tasks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no separate doc for java version of this except that it is said to do with com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet in the [doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) Nick provided.

```
Tip: If you have a Java app, you can use the Python appcfg.py tool by installing the Java
version of the remote_api handler, which is included with the Java runtime environment. 
The handler servlet class is com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet.
```

Here is some relevant code example for java version of this API usage [GAE/J datastore backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364310/gae-j-datastore-backup)