# using google app engine for a simple dynamic web site

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine

I want to upload a simple web site(Resume website) to google app engine.My web site is dynamic so i need to use database.I went through various tutorial where i found that google cloud sql can be used for a dyanamic website but it cost money.so my question is how can i use a database for my website without any payment.Is there any other ways.Plzz help me.

Comment: Keep working at it. I use GAE for free and I do store data in the database. You have to do their way. Read at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

Then use the Datastore API (from Java, Python or Go)

Comment: i know to use sql and mysql but this datasore is different than sql database.I will data to database manually so no data will be added from the web page.Web page will only retrieve those data.Will DataStore work in such case?

Comment: yes, Datastore is NOT a RDBMS and has a different API. However, it supports a "SQL like quety languane" GQL. In your use case you have to create an import function your self. Also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810394/export-import-datastore-from-to-google-app-engine

Comment: the other option is don't use appengine. :)