# Downloading Google App Engine Database

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I had created web application and deploy it in Google App Engine after I created table(entity) in Google App Engine datastore. My doubt is it possible to download the entity/database?

Answer (score 5):

to enable `remote_api`, add this to your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>remote-api</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>remote-api</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

details in this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/1bb013cbdd30750b

then, as shay mentioned, use the [bulk loader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html).

(added as an answer instead of a comment only because the XML wouldn't format nicely in a comment.)

Answer (score 3):

I had a simple requirement to dump entities from GAE Java based App and restore them to local  datastore. I could finally do it with following steps

1. Add RemoteApiServlet to web.xml and deploy the app

   > ```
   > <servlet>
   >     <servlet-name>RemoteApi</servlet-name>
   >     <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
   > </servlet>
   > <servlet-mapping>
   >      <servlet-name>RemoteApi</servlet-name>
   >      <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
   > </servlet-mapping>
   > ```
2. Download Google App Engine SDK for Python and unzip
3. Use bulkloader.py to dump the datastore from GAE

   > bulkloader.py --dump --application=s~appid
   >   --url=http://appid.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=xyz.dump

   --application is given as s~appid i.e. s tilda appid as app was using HR datastore. For Master/Slave datasotre plain appid will do.

   bulkload.py will prompt for login credentials for app. On authentication it will dump the entities to the file specified.
4. To restore use following command

   > bulkloader.py --restore --application=appid
   >   --url=http://127.0.0.1:8888/remote_api --filename=xyz.dump

   For local credentials use email admin and blank password. Even for HRD local datastore  use plain appid (s~appid restores data but entities can't be accessed in Development Console - Datastore viewer. I don't know why)

   Dump can be restored to same appid or even to a different appid

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the [BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)

Comment: I need some more examples,how to download data from google app engine datastore

Comment: i use this: `python2.5 appcfg.py download_data -A APP-ID --url http://APP-ID.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=datastore-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M).data`

Comment: In that bulkloaderlink also they explain using python.But i am using java so that i cant able to follow that example.I want some clear explanation about how download data using java in webapplication project

Comment: @user441392 Please read the entire link carefully as it describes the steps needed in order to use BulkLoader in Java. For future reference please state that you are using the Java GAE.

Comment: i had read and found this Tip: If you have a Java app, you can use the Python bulkloader.py tool
by installing the Java version of the remote_api handler, which is
included with the Java runtime environment. The handler servlet class
is com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet.

I understand i need to add the java remote api to my server app, and
use the python sdk tools on my desktop to upload and download data.
I'm just confused on how to set up the remote api in my java app. I'm sorry if i'm being obtuse.
i'm trying to find guidence on install the java remote_api in my app