# Backup and restore entities from Google App engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I am looking to implement a way to transfer data from one application to another programmatically in Google app engine. 
I know there is a way to achieve this with database_admin console but that process is very time inefficient.

I am currently implementing this with the use of Google Cloud Storage(GCS) but that involves querying data, saving it to GCS and then reading from GCS from different app and restoring it.
Please let me know if anyone knows a simpler way of transferring data between two applications programmatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this myself but it sounds like it should work: Use the data_store admin to backup your objects to GCS from one app, then use your other app to restore that file from GCS. This should be a good method if you only require a one time sync.

If you need to constantly replicate data from one app to another, introducing REST endpoints at one or both sides could help:

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/ (this is in Python, I know, but just define a version of your app for the REST endpoint)

You just need to make sure your model definitions match on both sides (pretty much update the app at both sides with the same deployment code) and only have the side that needs to sync data track time of last sync and use the REST endpoints to pull in new data. Cron Jobs can do this.

Alternatively, create a PostPut callback on all of your models to make a POST call every time a model is written to your datastore to the proper REST endpoint on the other app.

You can batch update with one method, or keep a constantly updated version with the other method (at the expense of more calls).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to move data between two App Engine applications or trying to export all your data from App Engine so you can move to a different hosting system?   Your question doesn't have enough information to understand what you're attempting to do.   Based on the vague requirements I would say typically this would be handled with a web service that you write in one application that exposes the data and the other application calls that service to consume the data.  I'm not sure why Cloud Endpoints was down voted  because that provides a nice way to expose your data as a JSON based web service with a minimum of coding fuss.

I'd recommend adding some more details into your question like exactly what are you trying to accomplish and maybe a mock data sample.

Comment: Both the applications are deployed on App Engine (with Java version). I am indeed using the WebServices approach where one application would write to GCS and other application would read from it but in this case the performance is not good enough for large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a backup of your data using bulkloader and then restore it on another application.

Details here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata?csw=1#Python_Downloading_and_uploading_all_data

Refer to this post if you are using Java:
[Downloading Google App Engine Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699114/downloading-google-app-engine-database/12458521#12458521)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this could be suitable for your concrete scenario, but [**Google Cloud Endpoints**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/overview) are definitely a simple way of transferring data programmatically from Google App Engine.

This is kind of the Google implementation of REST web services, so they allow you to share resources using URLs. This is still an experimental technology, but as long as I've worked with them, they work perfectly. Moreover they are very well integrated with GAE and the [**Google Plugin for Eclipse**](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloud_endpoints?hl=es).

You can automatically generate an endpoint from a [**JDO**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/) persistent class and I think you can automatically generate the client libraries as well (although I didn't try that).

Comment: As @earthtrip said, I don't understand why my answer has been downvoted, because I think it's perfectly valid taking into account the lack of details of the question...