# App Engine Bulkloader

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I am trying to use Bulkloader of google app engine but unfortunately could not understand what to do from documentation. It says add this part to app.yaml

builtins:
- remote_api: on

ok i have added. Then says that i have to execute this command

appcfg.py update

but i don't have any appcfg.py file. And also what is the command which executes this line?

Please somebody tell me what i am missing I use AppEngineLauncher to upload my project to server.. I have naver used a command to update or upload it.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

If you're using App Engine Launcher, simply click the Deploy button; it runs `appcfg.py update`.  appcfg is installed as part of the SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i had to solve it with command line not with app launcher. So i have found something that there is a "Make Symlinks" part in the app engine launcher menu. When you finish with that wizard you can use appcfg.py file from command line.

Comment: The command line `appcfg.py update` does the *exact same thing* clicking Deploy in the Launcher does.

Comment: @gurkan Has your question been solved then? You first need to deploy the changes to app.yaml, using either `appcfg.py update` or the Launcher. You then have to run `appcfg.py download_data --application=<app-id> --url=http://<app-id>.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=backup_file`

Answer (score 2):

In order to call it globally you must set the python path to include google appengine library, or call it from its excact location

```
~/google_appengine/appcfg.py update ~/project/path_to_your_yaml_file/
```

where ~ stands for you home folder.

Answer (score 1):

For those using the the *Java* GAE SDK, it comes wtih appcfg.sh, but doesn't support full features of apppcfg.py.  You need to also install the Python GAELauncher.  On Mac, it installs appcfg.py in /usr/local/bin.

Working only with my local datastore, I did not have an app.yaml, nor did I need to update it as per the [uploading data GAE documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata).  Just needed to [update the web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364310/gae-j-datastore-backup) with the RemoteApiServlet.

Main gotcha is the [Authentication error](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4721) while connecting to the local data store.  It may be specific to Mac and the Charles proxy work around mentioned in that thread likewise worked for me.  I did have to modify the default proxy port from 8888 to avoid conflict with my app.  The workaround is tedious and the trial version of Charles comes with limitations such as shutdown after 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

To use the main database for development, first download it from app engine:

```
bulkloader.py --dump --url http://<app name>.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename dump.bin
```

It will ask for an email and password (use your google login details).

To upload it to the development environment, make sure remote_api is
enabled in app.yaml
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Setting_Up_remote_api

Then run:

```
bulkloader.py --restore --url http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename dump.bin --application dev~<app name>
```

This time for the email, just leave it blank and hit enter.